# How to add a custom attribute to a XSD-1.1 validated XML Element

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

I want to add custom attributes to XML-elements in a validated document without changeing the original `*.xsd`. The XSD is version 1.1. I use python `xmlschema` library for validation.

The XML looks similar to this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<outer
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="root.xsd"
>

<inner custom:comment="do it now!" xmlns:custom="http://example.com/custom">
    <regular id="abc">Content</regular>
</inner>

</outer>
```

Currently the `custom:` element is rejected by `xmlschema`

```
Reason: '{http://example.com/custom}comment' attribute not allowed for element
```

Comment: Do you expect to write a new schema that includes the existing schema and extends the type (perhaps along the lines of https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#DerivExt)? It is not quite clear where/how you expect to add the custom attribute. And whether you expect the XML with an `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute to remain valid against that attribute. (that attribute seems wrong in your example as the sample has no namespace so it should be `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`)

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  If the schema doesn't allow the attribute then you have two choices: you can create a document that's invalid against the schema, or you can change the schema to make the document valid.